# How can I mark (flag) first unique record as 1 and the rest similar records as 0 in data frame in R continuation

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, dplyr

I need help with my data in R and dplyr.
My first problem was solved here: [How can I mark (flag) first unique record as 1 and the rest similar records as 0 in data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071207/how-can-i-mark-flag-first-unique-record-as-1-and-the-rest-similar-records-as-0/67071582#67071582) but I need improve this data. I use code as below:

```
df %>% mutate(drive = +!duplicated(paste(date, adress)))
```

and result is below:

```
 jobs, date, adress, drive 
1 111 28.03    bla     1 
2 111 28.03    bla     0 
3 111 28.03    bla     0 
4 111 28.03    bla     0 
5 111 28.03    bla     0 
6 111 28.03    bla     0 
7 111 28.03    bla     0 
8 111 28.03    bla     0 
9 111 28.03    bla     0 <- 9th record of the same job
10 111 28.03    bla     0 <- 10th record of the same job
11 345 05.03    bla     1 
12 111 28.03    bla     0  
13 236 28.03    abc     1
```

I need to improve a bit my dplyr and my data should be look that:

```
 jobs, date, adress, drive 
1 111 28.03    bla     1 
2 111 28.03    bla     0 
3 111 28.03    bla     0 
4 111 28.03    bla     0 
5 111 28.03    bla     0 
6 111 28.03    bla     0 
7 111 28.03    bla     0 
8 111 28.03    bla     0 
9 111 28.03    bla     0 <- 9th record of the same job
10 111 28.03    bla     1 <- 10th record, it should be 1 not 0. Sum of "the same jobs" above 9 give me again flag 1.
11 345 05.03    bla     1 <- new record of the job, so 1
12 111 28.03    bla     0
13 236 28.03    abc     1
```

So, first record give me 1, from 2-9 record of the same job give me 0, 10th record of the same job give me again 1, 11-19th record give me 0 and etc.

Comment: Do you mean 1st, 10th and other multiple of 10 th records are to be flagged as 1?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Record 1, 10 and 20 etc.

Comment: But your sample data does not contain any 'job' value?  Do you mean `date` change is a new job?

Comment: Ok, I edit a bit my data above.

Comment: Yes, my job is something like a job/merchant id. So we can group by job id (optionally address) and date.
If we have other date, but the same job id, start counting again.

Comment: see 2 answers below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there's more than one condition to test, I like to use `case_when` instead of nested `if_else`s. It works by running each test in order and outputting the part after the `~` for the first TRUE test. My last test here is just `TRUE`, so that anything not caught in the first two tests will produce a 0.

```
df %>%
  group_by(date, adress) %>%   # do these two vars define each "job"? 
  mutate(drive = case_when(
    row_number() == 1 ~ 1,
    row_number() %% 10 == 0 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Since there are only two output values, this could alternately be coded as

```
df %>%
  group_by(date, adress) %>%   # do these two vars define each "job"? 
  mutate(drive = if_else(row_number() == 1 | row_number() %% 10 == 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

base r approach

```r
df <- structure(list(jobs = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
                              111L, 111L, 111L, 345L, 111L, 236L), date = c("28.03", "28.03", 
                                                                            "28.03", "28.03", "28.03", "28.03", "28.03", "28.03", "28.03", 
                                                                            "28.03", "5.03", "28.03", "28.03"), adress = c("bla", "bla", 
                                                                                                                           "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", "bla", 
                                                                                                                           "bla", "abc")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
                                                                                                                                                         "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"), class = "data.frame")

transform(df, drive = ave(df$jobs, paste(df$jobs, df$date), FUN = function(x) +(seq_len(length(x)) == 1 | seq_len(length(x)) %% 10 == 0)))
#>    jobs  date adress drive
#> 1   111 28.03    bla     1
#> 2   111 28.03    bla     0
#> 3   111 28.03    bla     0
#> 4   111 28.03    bla     0
#> 5   111 28.03    bla     0
#> 6   111 28.03    bla     0
#> 7   111 28.03    bla     0
#> 8   111 28.03    bla     0
#> 9   111 28.03    bla     0
#> 10  111 28.03    bla     1
#> 11  345  5.03    bla     1
#> 12  111 28.03    bla     0
#> 13  236 28.03    abc     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

`dplyr` approach

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(jobs, date) %>%
  mutate(drive = +(as.numeric(row_number()) == 1 | as.numeric(row_number()) %% 10 == 0))
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#> # Groups:   jobs, date [3]
#>     jobs date  adress drive
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1   111 28.03 bla        1
#>  2   111 28.03 bla        0
#>  3   111 28.03 bla        0
#>  4   111 28.03 bla        0
#>  5   111 28.03 bla        0
#>  6   111 28.03 bla        0
#>  7   111 28.03 bla        0
#>  8   111 28.03 bla        0
#>  9   111 28.03 bla        0
#> 10   111 28.03 bla        1
#> 11   345 5.03  bla        1
#> 12   111 28.03 bla        0
#> 13   236 28.03 abc        1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Ok, thanks bro! I'm using dplyr so this solutions is closer to me. :) Works!
This solution with 'case_when' is also good.